# How do I switch between two colors on a UIView with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to set up a gesture recognizer (UITapGestureRecognizer) that works by clicking once and changing the view color to blue and in the second click to change it to yellow and then back to the default color red.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var squarView:UIView!;

    var squarIsBlue:Bool = true;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        squarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 130, y: 130, width: 150, height: 150));
        squarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();

        var squarTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapMe:");

        squarView.addGestureRecognizer(squarTap);

        squarView.userInteractionEnabled = true;


        view.addSubview(squarView);
    }



    func tapMe(sender:UIGestureRecognizer){

        squarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
        if (squarIsBlue == false){
            squarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor();
            if(squarIsBlue == true){
                squarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();

            }
            squarIsBlue = true

            }


            squarIsBlue = false;

            println("Squar Tapped!!!");

    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your squarIsBlue variable as int instead of Bool, to set color like, 0 = Red (Default), 1 = Blue, 2= Yellow,

So now, In viewdidLoad, set something like

```
squarIsBlue=0
squarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
```

Change your Tap Method like

```
func tapMe(sender:UIGestureRecognizer){

    squarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
    if (squarIsBlue == 0){
        squarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
        squarIsBlue=1;
    else if (squarIsBlue == 1) {
        squarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor();
        squarIsBlue =2
    }
    else if (squarIsBlue==2) {
        squarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
        squarIsBlue=0;
    } 
    println("Squar Tapped!!!");
}
```

Hope, this help you,

HTH, Enjoy coding !!

Answer (score 2):

You have mistake in tapMe logic. In this particular case it's better to use Integer variable instead of Boolean, since you have 3 states (Red,Blue,Yellow)...

Try this :

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var tapGesture : UITapGestureRecognizer!
    private var childView : UIView!

    private let colorPalette = [UIColor.redColor(),UIColor.blueColor(),UIColor.yellowColor()]
    private var currentColorIdx = 0 {
        didSet{
            childView.backgroundColor = colorPalette[currentColorIdx]
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTap:")

        childView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 130, y: 130, width: 150, height: 150))
        childView.backgroundColor = colorPalette.first
        self.view.addSubview(childView)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        childView.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGesture)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        childView.removeGestureRecognizer(self.tapGesture)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func didTap(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
        currentColorIdx = (currentColorIdx +  1 ) % colorPalette.count
    }

}
```